# What's the difference between async and sync func in setInterval node.js

Tags: node.js

I know the setInterval func is to run some periodic task. But I want to know what the difference between async and sync func. Here is an example.

```
const fetchFile = async ()=>{//dosometing}

setInterval(async()=>{
  fetchFile()
}, 1000)

setInterval(async()=>{
  await fetchFile()
}, 1000)

setInterval(()=>{
  fetchFile()
}, 1000)
```

Comment: There's no practical difference in your example. All 3 intervals will behave the same way.

Comment: Are these in node.js event loop all the same?

Comment: Do you need to wait for `fetchFile` to complete?

Comment: What happened if I need to wait for `fetchFile` complete. Will it block event loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no practical difference to the interval itself between any of your three implementations.  `setInterval()` does not pay any attention to the return value from the callback so it doesn't matter at all that the `async` version returns a promise.

You can declare it `async` if you want to use `await` inside the callback for your own implementation, but that won't affect the event loop whether you use `await` or `.then()`.  With `await`, as soon as you hit the `await` on a promise, the callback will return immediately and the event loop will be able to process other events.  The same is true if you do `fn().then()`.  While the asynchronous operation is running and the promise is waiting to get notified of completion, the event loop can process other events.

You may also want to know that there's no difference between these two:

```
fn(async()=>{
  fetchFile()
}, 1000)

fn(async()=>{
  await fetchFile()
}, 1000)
```

even outside of the `setInterval()` world.  Doing an await on the last line of an `async` function doesn't add anything.  It's just superfluous.  But, in the `setInterval()` case, since `setInterval()` doesn't pay any attention to the return value from the callback, there's no practical difference between any of your three implementations.

In fact, there's no difference between `return fetchFile()` and `return await fetchFile()` either in an `async` function.

---

In all your examples, you have NO error handling on `fetchFile()`.  If it rejects, you will have an unhandled rejection.  To catch those errors, you would either surround an `await` with `try/catch` or use `.catch()`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you pass `async` function callback to `setInterval` function which not expects `async` function in result you lack of proper error handling;

So if you want to run some periodic function I propose something like this, where you have more control on your code with error handling. Keep in mind that this could block event loop as your code could run thru microstask queeue only.

```js
const util = require('util');
const sleep = util.promisify(setTimeout);

const fetchFile = async () => {
  console.log('some async function');
};

async function fetchSomeFile() {
  try {
    await fetchFile();
    sleep(1000);
    fetchSomeFile();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}

fetchSomeFile().catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I propose to watch good presentation - Broken Promises - James Snell, NearForm https://youtu.be/XV-u_Ow47s0

Comment: Thanks. If I don't catch the error, will it block the event loop? Btw, what is microstask  queue?

Comment: Without catching error you can put your application in unpredictable state, and this is really bad situation. About microstack and event loop in general I recommend to read this blog post series https://blog.insiderattack.net/event-loop-and-the-big-picture-nodejs-event-loop-part-1-1cb67a182810